# It's Hot! Need somewhere to go Doc?

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking

You can have a HOLIDAY but as for the rest: which tiles, where, and why?  [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one has a surprising amount of crossover! It should be resolved like so:

> [image: Resolved Venn diagram]

The two ellipses represent:

> Left: Things that can be **followed by Martin**:
>
>  **APPLE** Martin (daughter of Coldplay's [Chris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Martin) and Gwyneth Paltrow), the car manufacturer [**ASTON** Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aston_Martin), the performer [**DEAN** Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dean_Martin), the renowned racehorse trainer [**PANCHO** Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancho_Martin), the singer [**RICKY** Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricky_Martin), and the actor and comedian [**STEVE** Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Martin).
>
>  Right: Things that can be **followed by Villa**:
>
>  [**ASTON** Villa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aston_Villa_F.C.) (the English football team), **HOLIDAY** villa, the Mexican revolutionary [**PANCHO** Villa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancho_Villa), the former Tottenham Hotspur footballer [**RICKY** Villa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricardo_Villa), and **ROMAN** Villa.
>
>  This means that **ASTON**, **PANCHO** and **RICKY** all appear in the crossover section!

The title offers multiple hints:

> A 'villa' is somewhere you might go to stay on a Mediterranean holiday for the summer heat, and [Doc Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doc_Martin) is a British TV drama.

Comment: Well done - hot as the weather!!!